# How to make into fives-block my byte numbers from the textbox?

Tags: c#, arrays, split, byte

Firstly, sorry my bad english for explaining my problem.

This seems to be an easy problem but I can't make this work. For example, when I enter a few numbers, I want to split them into fives block. After that, I want to do a math operation in each five numbers.

**1111011058108161105811110** ... it must do split,

such as,

```
*11110 x 5 =... in block array...
11058 x 5 =... in another block array.*
```

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes i have tried substring commands in for loop. But I haven't got the results yet.

Comment: why don't you edit your question, and post what you've got working so far. we can't help you debug unless you provide a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> output = new List<int>();
            string input = "1111011058108161105811110";
            for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 5)
            {
                output.Add(int.Parse(input.Substring(i,5)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this.

```
int numDigits = 5;


string str = "111101105810816110581111023";

str = str + new string(' ', numDigits - str.Length % numDigits);

for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i = i + 5)
{
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(i, numDigits));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} * 5 = {1}", number, number * 5);
}
```